# Getting Error while I Create a Function in Heroku MySQL Database Addin

Tags: mysql, heroku, cleardb

I've got this error:

> [Err] 1419 - You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you might want to use the less safe `log_bin_trust_function_creators` variable)

How can I get avoid getting this error in Heroku ClearDB MySQL database?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, were you able to resolve? I am considering migrating to Heroku Postgres because of this but still not 100% sure I'll be able to create stored procedures and triggers on their affordable plans either...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you're running into this issue is because of the replication configuration that ClearDB uses in their clusters and the fact that you're on a multi-tenant cluster. SUPER privileges are on their dedicated clusters so that you can create UDFs, stored procedures and triggers. You can upgrade to dedicated cluster.

Comment: Now how can I implement UDF in Heroku ClearDB MySQL?

Comment: To guard against this danger for servers that have binary logging enabled, MySQL 5.0.6 introduces the requirement that stored procedure and function creators must have the SUPER privilege, in addition to the usual CREATE ROUTINE privilege that is required. Similarly, to use ALTER PROCEDURE or ALTER FUNCTION, you must have the SUPER privilege in addition to the ALTER ROUTINE privilege. Without the SUPER privilege, an error will occur. Reference-http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-programs-logging.html